# In React a div has an height of a zero, then why its children are still showing on the screen

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

My goal is to hide div tag(id="two") when the button is clicked but also animate it like slideUp() in jquery, so after clicking on the button the div height set to zero and its work fine.

The problem is when the button is clicked the tags that are present in that div are still showing on screen why?

```css
#one{
height: 200px;
background-color:green;
}
#two{
height:100px;
background-color:yellow;
position: absolute;
z-index:1;
transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin>
        </script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script> 

<div id="root"></div>

<div id="container"></div>
        
        <script type="text/babel">
        const hide = () => {
        var elem = document.getElementById("two");
        elem.style.height = "0px";
     };
        ReactDOM.render(
           <div id="one">
              <h1>this is Div one</h1>
              <div id="two" >
                <h1>why this h1 is not hidden after the click</h1>
                <button onClick={hide} id="hide" >click me</button>
              </div>
              <div id="three" >
                <h1>this is div three</h1>
              </div>
           </div>,
          document.getElementById('container')
        )
        </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The div is still overflowing, you can add `overflow: hidden` to div 2 to "hide" it when the parent div shrinks.

```
#two {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out;
  overflow: hidden; // <----- hide any overflow
}
```

```css
#one {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}

#two {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>

<div id="container"></div>

<script type="text/babel">
  const hide = () => { var elem = document.getElementById("two"); elem.style.height = "0px"; }; ReactDOM.render(
  <div id="one">
    <h1>this is Div one</h1>
    <div id="two">
      <h1>why this h1 is not hidden after the click</h1>
      <button onClick={hide} id="hide">click me</button>
    </div>
    <div id="three">
      <h1>this is div three</h1>
    </div>
  </div>, document.getElementById('container') )
</script>
```

Comment: sir, thanks for helping me out, but i really want to know why is this happening. if i run this code without using react (using simple html, css and js) the code is working fine there is no need to set overflow. then why in react The div is still overflowing.

Comment: @Divesh TBH I don't quite follow your follow-on question... other than `ReactDOM` for rendering JSX into the DOM you aren't using React. Other than attaching the `onClick` handler a React way it's all still plain HTML. Do you have an example of vanilla HTML/javascript/CSS that reproduces the behavior you describe?

Comment: example  [simple form](https://codepen.io/diveshagarwal213/pen/NWpKqed) click on create account and in css see  #loginDiv no need of overflow

Comment: That example uses jquery and appears to also be moving elements up/down to make them "viewable".... more involved than simply setting the height of an element. You'll find that with CSS many times there more than a single way to achieve a visual effect.